# Linker error with FFImageLoading library

Tags: android, xamarin

When I try to build or debug the application using FFImageLoading I receive this error:

```
1>D:\Programmi\visualstudio\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1696,5): error MSB4018: errore imprevisto dell'attività "LinkAssemblies".
1>D:\Programmi\visualstudio\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1696,5): error MSB4018: Mono.Linker.MarkException: Error processing method: 'System.Void FFImageLoading.Forms.Droid.CachedImageFastRenderer/ElevationHelper::SetElevation(Android.Views.View,Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement)' in assembly: 'FFImageLoading.Forms.Droid.dll' ---> Mono.Cecil.ResolutionException: Failed to resolve System.Nullable`1<System.Single> Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.AndroidSpecific.Elevation::GetElevation(Xamarin.Forms.IPlatformElementConfiguration`2<Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.Android,Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement>)
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: `View.setElevation` requires API 21 at minimum. Please ensure your `<TargetFrameworkVersion>` is >= 21 (Android 5.0+)

Comment: Now i have set the minimum to 5.1 and target to 8.0 but the result doesn't change

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of what you changed? `<TargetFrameworkVersion` is also known as `compileSdkVersion`. `targetSdkVersion` is a different value with different behavior.

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/understanding_android_api_levels/#framework

Comment: Ah okay, compileSdkVersion is set on latest ( Android 8.0 (Oreo)) so i think this is not the problem:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Set target framework to the latest one
- Update your Xamarin.Forms version to 2.5
- Remove all `bin` & `obj` folders from all projects
- Rebuild

If you can't update Xamarin.Forms, use legacy package: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.FFImageLoading.Forms/2.2.25-pre-619-legac